# How quoted args are handled by /bin/time

Tags: linux, bash

I'm timing a custom binary in the form: `./prog --opt1=arg1 --opt2=arg2 --opt3="arg3"`

It's required that the third option have a quoted argument. In a script I save all the options:

`exec=./prog`
`opts="--opt1=arg1 --opt2=arg2 --opt3=\"arg3\""`

When I try to time the program, I'm getting an error with my program parsing the args. I'm guessing it's because it's seeing the last arg as not quoted. The output of `/bin/time`:

`\bin\time -v $exec $opts`

`Error parsing args` (from my program)
`Command being timed: "./prog --opt1=arg1 --opt2=arg2 --opt3="arg3""`

However when I just copy and paste, what it *claims* the command is, it runs fine:

`./prog --opt1=arg1 --opt2=arg2 --opt3="arg3"` --runs fine

What is `/bin/time` doing and how can I fix this? I'm guessing it has to do with the quotes, like maybe it runs eval or something. I'm not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting the entire command to a variable, and then evaluating that:

`$ full_cmd="/bin/time -v $exec $opts"`
`$ eval $full_cmd`

Comment: `eval` is the wrong way to do this; it has a well-deserved reputation for causing unexpected (and sometimes incomprehensible) bugs. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (and the many previous answers that link to it) for better ideas.